# how to make origin marker to bounce in directionsDisplay without using suppressmarkers:true?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have developed a route for 2 places using Google Maps Api .... Now I need that the origin marker A should be bounced but i don't want to make suppressMarker value to true ... I also don't want to add custom markers... Is there any way to make the default marker rendered by directionsDisplay itself to be bounced?

Comment: No, you can't do it without creating your own markers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change standart markers with letters to any other markers from google-chart service.
Let me show you how add some text on the marker:

```
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 
         markerOptions: { icon: "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=SomeText|FF0000|000000" }
    }),
```

or, you can take any other idea about change marker's look from there: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/dynamic_icons?hl=fr&csw=1#plain_pin